# How to retrieve all 4 coordinates of a rotated\scaled\translated UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, transform

I find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530328/retrieving-all-4-coordinates-of-a-rotated-uiimageview), and when I translate my view I can solve this problem successfully, but when I rotate or scale my view, I got a incorrect result. Anyone can help me?

Comment: what is your result? show your output. and what you want it to be.

Comment: @elk_cloner [this is my demo url](https://github.com/sunwell/Demo/tree/master/CoreAnimationDemo) and [this is the video](https://github.com/sunwell/Demo/blob/master/CoreAnimationDemo/CoreAnimationDemo/test.mp4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for your demo, and it's been tested. You could use the code from this issue's accepted answer: [Find Frame Coordinates After UIView Transform is Applied (CGAffineTransform)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523487/find-frame-coordinates-after-uiview-transform-is-applied-cgaffinetransform)

Use the code above as a UIView's **Category**, and then get the point like:

```
topleft = [view newTopLeft];
topright = [view newTopRight];
bottomleft = [view newBottomLeft];
bottomright = [view newBottomRight];
```

The result is:[image]

Comment: Maybe I didn't make the question clear. In my case, the view could be rotate  at any angle. And actually, after rotation, the origin of the view is not the left-top corner's coordinate.
And  [this is my demo url](https://github.com/sunwell/Demo/tree/master/CoreAnimationDemo) and [this is the video](https://github.com/sunwell/Demo/blob/master/CoreAnimationDemo/CoreAnimationDemo/test.mp4)

Comment: @BirdV, OK, I download your demo, and give your the response later.

Comment: There are four red point which records the rectangle's four corners' coordinates. What I want to see is that after I rotate or scale the green rectangle, the four red points are still at the corner of the rectangle. So that I can use these four red point to check whether that rectangle is out of a bigger rectangle range (the red line rectangle).